# pip package installation on MacOS failing with "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, xcode, gcc, pip

I had [PdfParser](https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser) installed and working on my Python3.7 environment. I was downloading another package when I was prompted for an xcode update, which I installed.

Immediately after, PdfParser wouldn't run, so I uninstalled it and attempted to reinstall. Now, I can't download it again:

`python3.7 -m pip install git+https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser --user`

```
unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) _NOEXCEPT {
              ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2564:7: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'auto_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'GlobalParams *'
          operator=(auto_ptr<_Up> __p) {
          ^
    2 warnings and 11 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qn/randomstring/T/pip-req-build-1u2_2dh6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qn/randomstring/T/pip-req-build-1u2_2dh6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qn/randomstring/T/pip-record-randomstring/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/dev/Library/Python/3.7/include/python3.7m/pdfparser Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can't say for sure, but I think updating xcode did something that changed how clang and gcc are operating on my computer. I've uninstalled and reinstalled xcode 12.4 and have xcode-select installed. Running the command `gcc` gives me `clang: error: no input files`.

Running `pip3 install git+https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser` gives me a slightly different error,

`error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1`

I'm on MacOS Catalina. I've replaced random strings like "u19ks74lm" with "randomstring" in the output above.

Comment: Someone else raised a [github issue](https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser/issues/29) about this. I've seen many of these errors for other packages, but I am wondering if there is a general gcc fix solution.

Comment: So I was able to fix it. But the fix wasn't pretty. I had a second laptop and was able to install it without issue. And then I airdropped the /site-package/ to my first laptop.